# Camunda User Profile Management with Docker

Tags: camunda

When camunda docker container is removed and added, I am loosing all the users and groups from the camunda application, I tried to manage user profile from outside of the docker through shared volume and it did not works, is there any solution to keep camunda users and groups outside of the docker or any option to export and import profiles systematically?

Answer (score 0):

Camunda uses a relational database for persistence. Your users and groups will also be stored in that DB. 
If you continuously loose all that data, I guess you are either working with an in-memory or file system (temp mount) datasource (h2?).

You should set up a postgres or mysql DB in a docker container and make sure you store its content correctly. If you then reconnect the camunda docker node to the datasource, you will have all store data again.